# arch linux xfce4 terminal font type gets wired after install some software

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, fonts, fontconfig, xfce4-terminal

I'm using arch linux and started to install some software after xfce4 desktop. However, My font "Monospace Regular" suddenly became thin and flat after some software installed (I don't know which one). I definitely haven't change any configuration about font type. They look like this in my screenshot.
[image]
How can I fix it?

Update: not only in xfce4-terminal, this change was applied in all of my software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

[Reinstall ttf-dejavu](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177690) will restore it.

And the software that cause this is gimp : )